# How to add more text to a PHP string

Tags: php, html, post, terminal

I making a PHP script which is powered by a POST request mainly, and it shows an HTML form which is like a command prompt, how can I simulate the text adding? I mean something like this (Mac OS X Terminal):
[image: term]

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Terminal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<?php
include("co.php");
echo $prompt;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$command=$_POST['command'];
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=\"es\">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">
    <title>Terminal</title>
    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" />

</head>";

$prompt .= "<header><p>Today is: ".date("M d")." of ".date("o")."</p><p class=\"command\"><label><form method=\"post\" action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" autocomplete=OFF>www@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":~$><input name=\"command\" type=\"text\" id=\"command\" size=\"40\" maxlength=\"500\" autofocus></label></form></p></header>";

$commandexp = explode(" ", $command);

if($commandexp[0] === "echo") {
    $prompt .= $prompt.$commandexp[1].$prompt;
    echo $prompt;
} else {
    echo "command not found";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can't do it only with PHP + HTML, you have to use JavaScript too.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a PHP problem. What you want is to be able to append to the displayed output, possibly after accepting user input each time. If so, you want a Javascript workaround to simulate the terminal effect.

Comment: Any clues on how to do that? I really want to append to the last output a prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a textbox field with no border and transparent background at the end of your command lines

and when user hits "enter", it sends the post request and refresh the list.

Comment: I already have that, just I need how to append to the last echoed string a new prompt

Comment: use javascript and ajax call to get the result and display it in a div which contains all lines

Comment: your problem is just design and positioning the field ? or you don't know how to save the command history ?

Comment: I really know very little about JS, you think this jQuery function would work? http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: It depends : if you want to do it by post or by ajax call. If each time the user hits enter to your field, you do a post and you save it to the server which returns all lines, you don't really need javascript (just for enter key on textfield). But if you want to do ajax call, you need javascript

Comment: I'm doing actually by POST, and I'll like to keep it via post

Comment: so you need to save the console output in database. Each time the user enter a new command, save it to your database, then load all the history and display it. At the end of the history (and not at the begin), display the textbox